# CRAN package release feedback: You write information messages to the console that cannot be easily suppressed

Tags: r, github, package, cran

I got the feedback from CRAN about package release.

And what is **suppressed** means?

**Feedback:**

You write information messages to the console that cannot be easily suppressed.
Instead of print()/cat() rather use message()/warning()  or if(verbose)cat(..) (or maybe stop()) if you really have to write text to the console.
(except for print, summary, interactive functions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We cannot see you code as you have not provided a reproducible example---so there is some guessing on my end involved---but it likely means you have one of

```
print()
cat()
```

in your code, just as the text says. And instead of `cat("Hello to my package\n")` you can also say `packageStartupMessage("Hello to my package\n")` for which the corresponding function `suppressPackageStartupMessages()` can be used to suppress.

For example:

```
> packageStartupMessage("Welcome to my package")  
Welcome to my package      
> suppressPackageStartupMessages(packageStartupMessage("Welcome ..."))    
>
```

The second one is suppressed, the first one isn't.  You need to find what prints to the console in your package (or any library it uses) and change it.

Similarly, `message()` can be suppressed, and `warning()` can be controled via warning levels.

The `r-package-devel` list is an excellent place for these questions, and the list archives will have examples of this too.

Comment: Hi, I just google ```r-package-devel``` but I did not find a place to ask question. Can you send me a link? Hugh help

Comment: Try `'r-package-devel mailing list` -- it hangs off the usual server at ETH Zuerich.  The (ugly, old, standard mailman) page is here:  https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-package-devel.  Note that you a) need to be subscribed to post and b) on the intial post only, a human needs to approve (and I am one of these admins).  So the first post may be delayed.  But even just _lurking_ and learning is highly recommended.